# Taking a PNG screenshot of a window, but keeping the aero transparency

Tags: c#, vb.net, transparency, screenshot, aero

Some time ago, I stumbled upon an excellent article about taking screenshots of specific windows in .NET, and doing something with black and white color rectangles behind those windows in order to preserve the aero effect when saving a screenshot to a PNG.
Well, I can't find that article anymore, mainly because crap sites and other stuff not at all associated with taking screenshots SEO'd their way into Google's results.
Does anyone know how I can take a screenshot of a specific window while preserving the aero effect?

Comment: What Aero effect are you talking about?  Glass?  The bleeding red close button effect?  Why would they matter for a screenshot of a single window?

Comment: I mean this: http://i53.tinypic.com/2qlh5av.jpg (the checkerboard stuff was added to highlight the translucent areas)

Comment: That's glass.  Other than the wow effect, it was meant to give the user a hint towards the Z-order of the windows.  Which is not exactly a problem when you make a screenshot of a window, there's only one window to look at.  Whatever might be behind it only messes up the screenshot.  Is that the problem you are trying to solve?  Make the background look consistent and not polluted by blurred pixels from the background windows?

Comment: I think he want the transparency in the saved PNG shot. So that the PNG he saves has save transparency as the window he takes a shot of. Am i right?

Comment: @HansPassant Yep, that's basically my problem. The other part of it being I dislike "normal" screenshots, I think they're ugly with all that other stuff in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant [this](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/01/30/recoveralpha) link. It describes how to revert alpha blending to get the "true" alpha values back.
Basically you have to put a white rectangle below the window, take a screenshot and do the same with a black rectangle. Then you can regain the alpha channel of the window, as described in the blog post linked above.

EDIT: Sorry, now i posted the corrected link.

Comment: Yep, that was the article. Thanks!